# Cordova invite facebook friends to App

Tags: facebook, cordova

I need to invite friends to use my app, whats the API call?

I read here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/invitable-friends/v2.2) that it is only accessible for Games app. Any workaround or solution for this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Have you found any solution? I want also for my app, not game,

Comment: hey,  using wizcorp plugin. this worked for me.

`window.facebookConnectPlugin.showDialog(
         {
             method: "apprequests",
             message: "Come on man, check out my app!."
         },
            inviteSuccess,
            function (error) { error }
        );`

Comment: @MayuriRuparel did it work for you

Comment: thanks it did work.... it shows only on mobile facebook app but not on the facebook which is opened from browser...do u have any idea about this? also can i add link to playstore or app store...thanks in advance :)

Comment: @MayuriRuparel yes about that, I still have no idea why, it only notify people on facebook app but on on browser. I'm using OnePlusOne 4.4, the link will redirect me to the playstore immediately, I would suggest you set your playstore or appstore link at the developer settings on facebook.

Comment: @MayuriRuparel  can anyone add more details..i am getting the app to open up a dialog box which makes me select friends but when i tap send to send to send invite it says "App not set up: App is still under developerment".. No notification shows up.